# Android Room update error by no such column

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-room

`@Query("update IMNotifyBean set read = ${true}")`

if the table IMNotifyBean is empty, it crash with error "no such column: true (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: update IMNotifyBean set read = true
"。

how can I fix it, such as by use "update IMNotifyBean if exits set read = ${true}"。

who can help me

My solution:
1 query
2 judge if is empty, it is empty, return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a syntax error. Replace your query with :

`@Query("update IMNotifyBean set read = 1")`

In your case, the room is compiling `true` as a column instead of a value.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution sounds reasonable. You can check if the table is empty before attempting the update. If it's empty, you can handle it appropriately, and if not, proceed with the update query.